# Velocity display unwanted character

Tags: java, velocity

I have this template:

```
#if ($unit.matches(".*Celsius"))\
    °\
#end#**# $unit \
```

However, the result display is always `Â°`, and the `Â` is displayed no matter what special character I use.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

did you check the way you load the template ? The encoding specified during file loading must be the same than the file itself.

If you use the same encoding writing and reading the file template, there is no need to escape chars.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally was just a simple escaping:

```
#if ($unit.matches(".*Celsius"))\
\u00B0\
\#end#**# $unit \
```